# mod_wsgi-express: error: no such option: --url-alias

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

I'm deploying an application with mod_wsgi-express, and I've a new error when launching the service :

```
oct. 12 09:15:29 Angara mod_wsgi-express[12284]: Usage: mod_wsgi-express start-server script [options]
oct. 12 09:15:29 Angara mod_wsgi-express[12284]: mod_wsgi-express: error: no such option: --url-alias /static /var/www/agenda-v3.example.tld/static     --url-alias /media /var/www/agenda-v3.example.tld/media
```

**The mod_wsgi-express application fails to launch...**

I've added the --log-directory directive to route logs to the `${SERVER_PATH}/log`, which works great (I can read the log files now), 
Have you any idea ? It worked before...

I've checked the `/var/www/agenda-v3.example.tld/media` and `/var/www/agenda-v3.example.tld/static` directories, they exist for now.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What is the full command you are running?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `WSGI_URL_ALIASES` is being passed through and interpreted as a single value rather than three separate arguments.

IOW, the argument is seen as single value of:

```
--url-alias /static /var/www/agenda-v3.example.tld/static
```

What I would actually suggest you do is use `setup-server` to pre-setup the `mod_wsgi-express` directory with the options you required. The only thing your init files then need to do is `apachectl start` and `apachectl stop`. All the stuff about options is recorded in scripts in the `mod_wsgi-express` directory.

See the PyPi page about using `setup-server`.

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi